# Catch Django order_by exception

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to let user get objects by sorting them via API: `example.com/foo?sort_by=STR`. I'm going to use `STR` in `.order_by`.

I found it's difficult to catch `FieldError` if Django cannot sort by `STR` (if `STR` keyword doesn't exist in the field) because QuerySets are lazy.

```py
foo_set = Foo.objects.order_by('bar')  # won't throw an exception
return foo_set[: 10]  # will throw FieldError
```

I cannot check if `STR` field exists before because I want to let user sort in the reverse sequence (`foo.order_by('-bar')`). So I put `foo_set[0]` in `try` but it's horrible (exception if foo_set is empty, hardcoded getting the first element).

```py
try:
  foo_set[0]
except FieldError:
  process_bad_request(...)
except IndexError:
  pass
```

What way to check would you use?

Comment: If you're not going to further process the query set (further down the code path) and it's going to be evaluated anyway, you can force it to evaluate by setting `foo_set = list(Foo.objects.order_by('bar')` which will throw your exception. But why not actually checking if `STR` is a field (you can easily remove the first `-` character if it's there).

Comment: @dirkgroten, right now I'm considering about checking if `STR` is in `(f.name for f in Foo._meta.fields)` and adding the second optional argument `reversed=true`.

Comment: Yep, that would be a cleaner approach I'd say. You could also add a list of safe fields to order by in your model and use that instead (in general, I don't think it's appropriate for 3rd parties to be able to order by all the fields on my models, as some might give away sensitive information, e.g. id tells someone how many records you have and date fields tell someone when a record was last added/updated).

Comment: @dirkgroten, you're right! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question "How to catch that exception?" @dirkgroten suggested to get list of QuerySet. That forces Django to try getting in order that throws an exception.

```py
try:
  list(Foo.objects.order_by('blahblah'))  # throw an exception
except FieldError:
  ...
```

But in my case (and cases when user gives clear field names) it's better to check before ordering. Moreover, it can be unsafe to check by every name (what `Foo._meta.fields` can give) because some data (i.e. id) mustn't be shown. So I created a tuple of "safe" names and I check that `STR` is in that tuple.

```py
field_names = ('show_until', 'title')  # "safe" field names
sort_by = request.GET.get('sort_by', 'title')  # remind that I get STR as argument
if sort_by not in field_names:  # if STR is not in "safe" names
  return HttpResponseBadRequest(
    'sort_by should be existent field name. Choices are: {}.'.format(
      ', '.join(field_names)
    )  # then process as you want
  )
```